# Centreon 3.4 : host added but not monitored

Tags: centreon

I downloaded the Centreon 3.4.6 VM (OVF on https://download.centreon.com/) and it runs fine on VMWare.

Here all the versions :

[image]

A default host is present : centreon-central.
I would like to monitor another local host : localvm1.
The host has been added :

[image]

It is based on the template `generic-active-host`.
It have a service `Ping :
[image]

Problem: the host not present in the monitoring section ...

[image]

I have rebooted 3-4 times the Centreon VM and nothing has changed.

After a `grep` in `/var/`, the host seems to be in the MySQL database (this is the only reference in `/var/`, so nothing in logs files ...) :

[image]

Could you help me ?

Can't find anything in the documentation ...

Answer (score 0):

It's not enough to just add the host, you also have to add services to the host (this is what's actually getting monitored)

EDIT:

And after you make changes to the configuration you need to generate a new config file. If you don't, the configuration won't come into effect.

```
Go into the menu: Configuration ==> Pollers
Choose the pollers which you want to export configuration
Click on Apply configuration
Check the boxes: Generate Configuration Files and Run monitoring engine debug (-v)
Click on Export

Uncheck the boxes: Generate Configuration Files and Run monitoring engine debug (-v)
Then check the boxes: Move Export Files and Restart Monitoring Engine
Click on Export
```

Comment: I've updated the question : the host have a service "Ping".

Comment: OK, I've edited my answer; please check it out.

Comment: And after you've done all this - wait 5-10 minutes and you will see the results (the checks run in intervals)

Comment: I have seen "Conf. Changed" : "YES" on the poller "Central" (main poller). I've done your procedure. The engine has restarted. Now the "Conf. Changed" is set to "NO". I've been waiting for 20 min and nothing changed ... But "Scheduling Time" of "Ping" service is set to "0 min / 0min". Is it normal ?

Comment: They refer to the time periods of _Execution of check commands_ and _Sending of notifications_ respectively. Change both of them to 00:00-24:00